# Clicking a link in IE using Selenium does not work

Tags: selenium, junit

I'm seeing a strange result, when I put the following in my JUnit code:

```
selenium.click("link=Test Link");
```

It works when I'm testing in Firefox but throws an error saying it can't find the link when I test in IE.

Is this a limitation with IE?  That seems like a severe selenium bug, I'm banking I'm missing something... ;)

Comment: Did you try css locator to make sure issue is happening only when you use link=?

Comment: Yes, when I use IE and CSS locator it works.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have the required setUp method for starting the test in IE which is;

```
public void setUp() throws Exception{
   setUp("http://www.google.com", "*iexplore");
}

public void test01 throws Exception{
   selenium.open("/");
   //I'd just wait for page to load before clicking anything
   // that might be a reason...

   selenium.waitForPageToLoad("20000");
   selenium.click("link=test link");
}
```

I hope that fixes it...

Comment: Mehmet, that's pretty much my code, but the click is not finding the link.  If I simply switch the *iexplore to *chrome, it works.

Comment: I just searched it a little bit, it seems like you are not the only one having this issue. I didn't read through everything but, I'd look at [here](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users)

Comment: Thanks Mehmet, I think I will end up doing it differently, it's too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any frames on the page? In my experience different browsers can show slight differences in their tolerance for allowing Selenium to find elements if you do not explicitly drill down (or up!) to the specific frame containing the element in question.

Comment: I do have frames on that page, but the links I am trying to click are not in those frames